# SharePoint "Chrome Type" issue in publishing pages

Tags: css, sharepoint

Although my issue is related to SharePoint, I think it's also a html/css issue, so I post the question here. If you are familiar with SharePoint, you can follow the steps to reproduce the issue (or you can just skip this part, it's ok):

1. Create a publishing page, and the Page Layout is "(Welcome Page) Blank Web Part page"
2. Add two Web Parts in "Top Left" and "Top Right".
3. Set the "Chrome Type" to "None/Border Only" in the first Web Part (The Top Left one)

And so will see the issue in non-IE browsers (they should be in the same line):

[image]

To make it simple, I create a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLlBH) :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ms-table {
            display: table;
        }
        .ms-fullWidth {
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .tableCol-75 {
            display: table-cell;
            min-width: 74.9%;
        }
        .cell-margin {
            margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
        }
        .tableCol-50 {
            display: table-cell;
            min-width: 49.9%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
        <div class="tableCol-75">
            <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
                <div class="cell-margin tableCol-50">
                    <div class="ms-fullWidth">
                        <div class="ms-fullWidth ">
                            <div>
                                <div width="100%">
                                    <div wpid="ctl00_ctl40_g_0b541c21_2ea1_46e2_bc3e_7c10ff98186d">
                                        <table id="myWP1">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p>hello</p>
                                                        <p>hello</p>
                                                        <p>hello</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell-margin tableCol-50">
                    <div class="ms-fullWidth">
                        <div class="ms-fullWidth ">
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <span><h2 style="text-align:justify;"><nobr><span>Web Part Title</span>
                                    <span></span>
                                    </nobr>
                                    </h2>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div width="100%">
                                    <div wpid="ctl00_ctl40_g_0b541c21_2ea1_46e2_bc3e_7c10ff98186d">
                                        <table id="myWP2">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p>hello</p>
                                                        <p>hello</p>
                                                        <p>hello</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Web Part also has this issue in all browsers. I am not familiar with css, so I really don't know how to analysis the issue. But I found something interesting:

1. If I add a span tag (or other) before "myWP", then there is no issue. ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/atfon))
2. If I delete the table ("myWp") and use a div instead, no issue again. ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hlwbx))

Currently I choose the first way to fix it, but I don't know why. Is it a right way? What is the reason of this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are errors in the piece of HTML you posted, such as duplicate IDs, `<h2>` in `<span>` and so on. Now different browsers respond differently to errors, so it's not surprising that you get different results. Also, the HTML here doesn't have a DOCTYPE, but the codepens do. That also causes differences. And is `id="ms-fullWidth"` actually supposed to be `class="ms-fullWidth"`? The id does nothing.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right. `id="ms-fullWidth"` is supposed to be `class="ms-fullWidth"`. Actually, I can only control `table#myWP`, others are controlled by the system. So I can not fix the error like `<h2>` in `<span>`.

Comment: So does the actual HTML contain the DOCTYPE, or was that put in by the codepen website? Having a DOCTYPE or not causes differences in display between IE and other browsers.

Comment: @MrLister The actual page contains the `DOCTYPE`.